# How do I process an entire row when using rowwise()?

Tags: r, tidyverse

My dataset consists of numeric columns, with some missing (i.e. NA) values. I want to find the rows that consist *entirely* of NA values. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

frm <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C,
  11, 22, 33,
  14, NA, 37,
  10, 29, 36,
  NA, NA, NA,
  18, 28, 38
)
```

I could process each row in a for-loop, using is.na() and all(), but I'd like to find a "tidy" solution. This is the best I could do:

```
frm %>%
 rowwise %>%
 summarize(all_values_missing = is.na(A) & is.na(B) & is.na(C))
```

But this approach doesn't scale to datasets with lots of columns and nontrivial column-names. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `c_across` function to help. For example

```
frm %>%
  rowwise %>%
  summarize(all_values_missing = all(is.na(c_across())))
```

If you only need a subset of columns the `c_across()` will accept tidy selectors as well.

Comment: This solution is the one that most closely fits in with the way I framed the problem: with the explicit use of rowwise().

Answer (score 2):

The dplyr package has some functions designed to handle rowwise logical operations swiftly (`if_any` or `if_all`).
For this question, we can use either. No need for `rowwise`.

```
library(dplyr)

frm %>% mutate(all_values_missing = if_all(everything(), is.na))

# A tibble: 5 × 4
      A     B     C all_values_missing
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>             
1    11    22    33 FALSE             
2    14    NA    37 FALSE             
3    10    29    36 FALSE             
4    NA    NA    NA TRUE              
5    18    28    38 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your return value to be?

You can use `pmap_lgl` to iterate rowwise over your dataframe and return a logical vector of whether the row was all NA:

```r
> pmap_lgl(frm, ~all(is.na(.x)))
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You can embed this in your dataframe in a tidy manner via:

```r
> frm %>%
+   mutate(all_na = pmap_lgl(., ~all(is.na(.x))))
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      A     B     C all_na
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
1    11    22    33 FALSE 
2    14    NA    37 FALSE 
3    10    29    36 FALSE 
4    NA    NA    NA TRUE  
5    18    28    38 FALSE
```